# Check the sizeof of all variadic arguments is the same

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would like to be able to check, at compile-time using `static_assert`, that all variadic arguments to a class are created with the same size.

Here is the code I have come up with, but it doesn't work:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
class MyClass {
    static size_t arg_reference_size;

    constexpr static bool size_is_equal() {
        return true;
    }

    template<typename First, typename... Others>
    constexpr static bool size_is_equal() {
        return arg_reference_size == sizeof(First) && size_is_equal<Others...>();
    }

    template<class First, typename... Others>
    constexpr static bool check_args_size() {
        arg_reference_size = sizeof(First);
        return size_is_equal<Others...>();
    }

    static_assert(size_is_equal<Args...>(), "");
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "doesn't work"?

Comment: If you are willing to change the signature of `MyClass`, then you can just utilize a fold expression directly.  Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43fa1ffd4bbf1f4a

Comment: What should happen for empty pack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd move the type trait out of the class:

```cpp
template<class T, class... R>
inline constexpr bool is_same_size_v = (... && (sizeof(T) == sizeof(R)));

template<typename... Args>
class MyClass {
    static_assert(is_same_size_v<Args...>);
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int, unsigned> x;
    //MyClass<char, long double> y; // will very likely fail
}
```

---

If you'd like to keep the type trait internal to your class and build on your current idea, you could make sure that `size_is_equal()` is declared to return a *type* with a `static constexpr` variable set to `true` or `false` depending on the template parameters. You don't need an actual implementation of the function. The returned type will be enough. Here `std::integral_constant<bool, true>` or `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` will be returned - and they are different types with a `static constexpr bool value` variable. You can then use `decltype(<the returned type>)::value` to get to the actual result.

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
class MyClass {
    template<typename First, typename... Others>
    static auto size_is_equal() ->
        std::integral_constant<bool, (... && (sizeof(First) == sizeof(Others)))>;

    static constexpr bool size_is_equal_v =
        decltype(size_is_equal<Args...>())::value;

    static_assert(size_is_equal_v, "nope");
};
```

---

A third option, if you really want your functions to have implementations and if you can't use C++17 fold expressions and need recursion instead:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
class MyClass {
    template <typename... Ts>
    // SFINAE to only make this match if the param pack is empty:
    constexpr static typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 0, bool>::type
    size_is_equal() {
        return true;  // or `false` if an empty parameter pack should not be
                      // allowed
    }

    template <typename>  // a single parameter to terminate recursion
    constexpr static bool size_is_equal() {
        return true; // a single parameter is always true
    }

    // Take at least two template parameters and pass one of them on to the
    // recursive call:
    template <typename First, typename Second, typename... Others>
    constexpr static bool size_is_equal() {
        return sizeof(First) == sizeof(Second) &&
               size_is_equal<Second, Others...>();
    }

    static_assert(size_is_equal<Args...>(), "not equal size");
};
```

Comment: You could also do `int32_t` and `int64_t` which will always fail

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili True, but then it might hypothetically fail for another reason since those are optional `typedef`s.

Comment: `MyClass<char, char[2]>` will always fail portably for the same reason, but this is starting to become a bit more obscure maybe